# Generate delta from new message and old/previous message biztalk

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-orchestrations

We are pulling an XML report via a web service from a send adapter daily (currently just placing it in a folder via FILE adapter). What is the simplest way to compare new reports/messages against previous reports/message of the same orchestration to get the delta/difference (rather than getting the previous days report from an adapter (FILE, custom DB, etc.)?

Best case scenario for us would be to have the orchestration pull the previous day's message from the message box (is that possible?if so, how?), compare the new message/report to the previous days message/report and create a new report in the same schema but including only the records that have changed (delta).

Comment: Can you clarify, are you trying to compare the data for business purposes or are you trying to compare the Messages for some diagnostic purpose?

Comment: Business Purpose. We just need to know what records have changed in the target system we are getting the report from. Rather than load them into a custom database and run a delta report I would prefer to simply pull the previous days message from the messagebox (this is a daily process) compare to the new message coming in from the send adapter (identifying records that have changed) and then send the new constructed message (delta) to an outbound adapter.

Comment: Usually once a message is processed it won't be in the message box anymore.  So you would have to either persist the message by having a long running Orchestration or persisting it to another database.    Is it possible to get the source system to send a delta rather than having to compare in BizTalk?

Comment: This is more of a proof of concept for us to determine the level of flexibility Biztalk has. I found [this](https://www.connected-thoughts.com/2008/04/02/3-ways-of-programatically-extracting-a-message-body-from-the-biztalk-tracking-database/) guide for pulling messages from message box and built my own assembly with it and its working. I still need an efficient way to compare the messages/reports though. I'll either use a custom assembly again (probably inefficient) or use functoids and a mapper (similar to [this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/BizTalk-Mapper-Patterns-14888892) )